# Save/export color profile calibration in Mac OS X

Tags: mac, export, color-profiles

A colleague and I both have identical iMacs with identical external Dell monitors.  Our iMac monitors look about the same, but he's got his color on the Dell looking perfect and I can't seem to get mine to match it.  Is there a way to just export the color profile on his side and import it over on my side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find the color profiles in `/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/`. Just copy them to the other machine, same directory, and select in *System Preferences » Displays » Color*. Make sure to deselect *Show profiles for this display only*.

Answer (score 1):

I calibrated my Dell display using SuperCal and its color profile was stored in my home directory in `/Users/myuser/Library/ColorSync/Profiles`.